# react-router-dom v6 nested routes doesn't work with element in the parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The [Nested Routes example](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes) provided by React Router V6 docs does not work. I tried this with `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"` and the children routes doesn't work. It returns the root element when I try to access `/parent` or `/parent/child`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<div>Root</div>}>
      <Route path="parent" element={<div>Parent</div>}>
        <Route path="child" element={<div>Child</div>} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `/parent` route just works if I remove the `element` from the root route: `<Route path="/" >`. But in this case I get the warning below, the page `'/'` is empty and the `'/parent/child'` still doesn't work.

```
Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
```

I would really appreciate any help to better understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For nested `Route` components, the parent layout component needs to render an `Outlet` for them to be rendered into.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={(
        <div>
          Root
          <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here
        </div>
      )}
    >
      <Route
        path="parent"
        element={(
          <div>
            Parent
            <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here
          </div>
        )}
      >
        <Route path="child" element={<div>Child</div>} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You need to read a bit further down in the doc you linked to get the explanation:

> Notice the inner component that changed with the URL (`<SentInvoices>`
> and `<Invoice>`). The parent route (`<Invoices>`) is responsible for
> making sure the matching child route is rendered with `<Outlet>`.
> Here's the full example:
>
> ```
> import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
>
> function App() {
>   return (
>     <Routes>
>       <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
>         <Route path=":invoiceId" element={<Invoice />} />
>         <Route path="sent" element={<SentInvoices />} />
>       </Route>
>     </Routes>
>   );
> }
>
> function Invoices() {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <h1>Invoices</h1>
>       <Outlet />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> function Invoice() {
>   let { invoiceId } = useParams();
>   return <h1>Invoice {invoiceId}</h1>;
> }
>
> function SentInvoices() {
>   return <h1>Sent Invoices</h1>;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese  I tried it, with the exact same code, using "react": "^17.0.2", but in the nested routes the content is also nested. In `/parent/child`, for example, the content is: `Root Parent Child`, but it should be only `Child`.

Comment: @JeffPal Can you clarify in a little more detail that last comment? I don't really understand it. Perhaps update your question with these new relevant details as well?

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese sorry for the delay. I meant I tried your code example, all the paths work but the sub-paths' content are merged to it's parent's content. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @JeffPal Ah, I see... it sounds like you are saying the "child" content is rendering under the parent content? The solution here is to use the `Outlet` in the layout, and move the "parent" content into it's own index route.